# Usage of boost lambdas

Tags: c++, boost, boost-lambda

I am new to boost and trying to write some simple programs to understand it. Here in the following piece of code I am trying to fill an array with random numbers. Here is my code:

```
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    srand(time(NULL));
    boost::array<int,100> a;
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), _1=rand());
```

But it looks like `rand()` is getting evaluated only once and my array is containing the same  values for every element. Can anybody point what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You don't need to use boost::lambda to fill the array with random numbers, by the way. You could e.g. use `std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), &rand);`.

Comment: may be I can do that, but still I would like to know why this approach won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you need to use [delayed function call](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions)

```
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), boost::lambda::_1= boost::lambda::bind(rand) );
```

Here is another interesting situation: [Delaying constants and variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html)

Comment: Thanks..that worked perfectly, I'll check on how delayed function calls work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is equivalent to the following one:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;

srand(time(NULL));

boost::array<int, 100> a;
int i = rand();

std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), _1=i);
```

What you want is rand to be invoked for each element; this is usually done using std::generate, as @MP24 noted in a comment:

```
std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), rand);
```